# Summing something that looks binomial

Tags: summation

I have a sum that looks like

$\sum_{j=0}^{k/2} \frac{k!}{(k-2j)!j!(2d)^j }p^{k-j}(1-p)^j$.

$p \in (0,1), d$ is an integer $> 1$

I am wondering is at least an approximate sum is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm replacing $k = 2r$ because I don't want to deal with the issue of odd $k$.

The exact sum is known to be expressible in terms of Tricomi's form of confluent hypergeometric function $U(a,b,x)$.  When 
$$
U(a,b,x) = \frac1{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty t^{a-1}(1-t)^{b-a-1}e^{-xt}\,dt
$$
(sometimes called CFGs of the second kind).  In terms of that, the formal sum is

$$(-1)^r\left( \frac{(4p(1-p)}{(2d)!} \right)^r U\left((-r,\frac12,-\frac{(2d)!p}{4(1-p)}\right)
$$

The asymptotic behavior of this CFG looks like 
$$
C(-1)^r \left(\frac{(2d)!p}{4(1-p)}\right)^r
$$
where $C$ is a generalized hypergeometric series with $1$ as its leading term.

The $(-1)^r$ factor will disappear against the identical factor inside the behavior of the CFG, leaving an asymptotic behavior of
$$
\left(\frac{(2d)!p}{4(1-p)}\right)^r
$$

And this almost exactly cancels the factor $\left( \frac{(4p(1-p)}{(2d)!} \right)^r$ outside the CFG, leaving a result of $p^r$.

So by this reasoning this sum should go like $p^{k/2}$.  However, this all takes lots of liberties with convergence of series and so forth, so I would not trust it too heavily.